# How do I import links from a website to Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula

How do I get the links from this website to enter them into google sheets, I need to have a list of the links for twitter of every picture.

Here is the Website:
https://www.nft.nyc/speakers

Comment: every image has a link for twitter. I want to import those to a google sheet

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=importxml("https://www.nft.nyc/speakers","//@href[contains(.,'https://twitter.com')]")
```